# Org Mode Latex fragment preview fails to convert tex to png

Tags: emacs, preview, org-mode

I have a windows 10 machine, and MikTex. Whenever I try to toggle the preview of the I get an error in messages buffer below:

```
org-create-formula-image-with-dvipng: Failed to create png file from
c:/Users/dilzeem/AppData/Local/Temp/orgtex9552Y9a.tex`
```

I have looked at the log file, but can't figure out why it is not working. There is a .tex file, and a .dvi file in the folder, but no .png.

I am also using Spacemacs, instead of Emacs. I have also tried to use imagemagick but get the same result.

This is an example of what I try to preview:`$P_{net}=r_1^2 - r_2^2$`. I press `C-c C-x C-l` to `org-toggle-latex-fragment`

Comment: Have you a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of the code that create the error?

Comment: I am not sure if if the above edit is what you mean?

Comment: Yes it's what I mean, however I've no error with this code and the preview. I'm using emacs 24.4.1 and org-mode 8.3.2 from elpa

Comment: Okay thanks. I am using the same emacs version. I am not sure how to check which org-mode but I have the latest version.

Comment: @dilzeem `M-x org-version`

Comment: you can know your org version with `M-x org-version`

Comment: Ohh thanks. Found out it is org-mode 8.3.3.

Comment: you should try with emacs instead of spacemacs perhaps it will help

Comment: I got it to work now. thanks for your assistance. I will write up how I solved it in the original question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a missing package installation solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**
There was a missing package was required to do the preview. I ran `dvipng` in the cmd line on a .dvi file and it installed the missing packages. The preview now works. The missing package was `zhmetrics`.